# Accessing a complex key in a config file

Tags: groovy, nextflow

I'm trying to access a variable in a `nextflow.config` file during the execution of a pipeline. I want to supply `image_standard` as a string in `run.nf` and I want to receive `eu.gcr.io/proj_name/image1:latest` as an output. I figured out a way to obtain the content of the `.config` file within the nextflow script, but I don't know how to access this specific property.

This is my `nextflow.config` file:

```
process {
    withLabel: image_standard {
        container = "eu.gcr.io/proj_name/image1:latest"
    }
    withLabel: image_deluxe {
        container = "eu.gcr.io/proj_name/image2:latest"
    }
}
```

the `run.nf`

```
  x =  workflow.configFiles[0]
  Properties properties = new Properties()
  File propertiesFile = new File("${x}")
        propertiesFile.withInputStream {
        properties.load(it)
    }
    log.info "${properties.process}"
```

Which just prints the line:

`{`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try instead slurping the config file and selecting the process you want using the ProcessConfig class and the [applyConfigSelector()](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/blob/v20.10.0/modules/nextflow/src/main/groovy/nextflow/script/ProcessConfig.groovy#L301-L340) method:

```
import nextflow.config.ConfigParser
import nextflow.script.ProcessConfig

def config_file = file("${baseDir}/nextflow.config")
def config = new ConfigParser().setIgnoreIncludes(true).parse(config_file.text)

def process = new ProcessConfig([:])
process.applyConfigSelector(config.process, 'withLabel:', 'image_standard')

println(process.container)
```